# Ldap on Centos7: why my RootDN doesn't work?

Tags: openldap

On a fresh centos7 ldap server

I use a ldif like this

```
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: dc=Manager,dc=mydomo,dc=mydom
-
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to *
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write
  by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=mydomo,dc=mydom" write by * none
-
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Of course hash is correct

The command go ok but if i try a simple ldap insert..

```
ldapadd -x -D "dc=Manager,dc=mydomo,dc=mydom" -w mycorrectpass -f init2.ldif
```

give me

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Why?
ldap is correct running,i can insert only with ldapi and -Y external
the user ldap has correct perms on dirs.

Comment: "mycorrectpass" looks to be incorrect in the first place.

Comment: No,is correct,i have used for hash slappasswd -s mycorrectpass

Comment: Indeed, I have reproduced the problem with a fresh openldap installation. There is something odd going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, is possible to use the external auth wich use sasl

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f init2.ldif
```